# Redirect URI from this request does not match one from the authorize request even though they're the same

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, simple-oauth2

So I am using ORY/Hydra to host an OAuth 2.0 Server and am in the process of building a sample client to demonstrate the flow. I call the `/oauth2/auth` endpoint with the `redirect_uri` in the query params, and I use `simple-oauth2` to later call `/oauth2/token` to fetch the access tokens.

I can create a client through my API into the Hydra server and the response is a valid JSON with the one of the callback URL's being `http://localhost:3000/callback'

```
{
    "id": "cbf09258-7f8e-4147-93c1-aa7e2e7b99b3",
    "name": "Test App 1",
    "clientId": "515e7876-881e-4f3a-b489-20ed7300c745",
    "clientSecret": "deleted",
    "clientSecretExpiresAt": 0,
    "token": 
"$2a$08$bWZMUf5wgEpOcoUjsJ5l/uS5LaTmqrC40FTnfegzelE69H8JAFrMW",
    "callbackUrl": [
        "127.0.0.1:3000",
        "localhost:3000/callback",
        "http://localhost:3000/callback"
    ],
    "url": "",
    "imageBanner": "",
    "imageIcon": "",
    "createdAt": "2019-02-04T19:14:22.193152Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-02-04T19:14:22.193152Z"
}
```

The flow starts at `localhost:3000/callback` as well and my jade file renders a link to call `/oauth2/auth` as follows

```
block content
    h1 Whew
    a(href="http://localhost:4444/oauth2/auth?client_id=" + clientid + "&scope=openid offline&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&state=haardik123") Authorize
```

Finally, the handler includes code to call `/oauth2/token` if a `code` param is present in the query as follows: (`callback.js`)

```
const oauth2 = simpleOauthModule.create({
    client: {
        id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
    auth: {
        tokenHost: 'http://localhost:4444',
        tokenPath: '/oauth2/token',
        authorizePath: '/oauth2/auth',
    },
});

// Authorization uri definition
const authorizationUri = oauth2.authorizationCode.authorizeURL({
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    scope: 'openid offline',
    state: 'haardik123',
});

router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    var clientid = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
    var code = query.code;
    const options = {
        code,
    };

    if (code) {
        try {
            const result = await oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken(options);

            console.log('The resulting token: ', result);

            const token = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);

            return res.status(200).json(token)
        } catch(error) {
            console.error('Access Token Error', error.message);
            return res.status(500).json('Authentication failed');
        }
    }
    res.render('callback', {
        clientid: clientid
    });
});
```

The flow goes normally until I get redirected back to `localhost:3000/callback` with a `code` in the query params but then it says `Status 400: Bad request - Authentication Failed`

Hydra logs show that

```
time="2019-02-04T19:16:05Z" level=info msg="started handling request" method=POST remote="172.29.0.1:35130" request=/oauth2/token
time="2019-02-04T19:16:05Z" level=error msg="An error occurred" description="The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed" error=invalid_request hint="The \"redirect_uri\" from this request does not match the one from the authorize request."
time="2019-02-04T19:16:05Z" level=info msg="completed handling request" measure#http://localhost:4444.latency=60183900 method=POST remote="172.29.0.1:35130" request=/oauth2/token status=400 text_status="Bad Request" took=60.1839ms
```

I'm not sure why the redirect_uri won't match as it seems like I did everything fine -- would love any insight on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by adding a `redirect_uri` to the `options` object being passed to `oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken(options)`

Changing the object to

```
const options = {
    code,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
};
```

worked!